# How to catch/forward MouseWheel event to several objects?

Tags: java, swing, mousewheel, yfiles

I am using [yFiles](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles) library and I am handling a [Graph2DView](https://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/y/view/Graph2DView.html) object named `view`. To activate mouseWheel scroll for this object, I have to add a listener in [registerViewListeners](https://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/y/view/Graph2DViewMouseWheelScrollListener.html) function. However, I also want to be notified also in myClass `mouseWheelMoved` function when mouseweel

```
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass implements MouseWheelListener {
    
    Graph2DView view;  
    // ..... 

    @Override
    protected void registerViewListeners()   
    {  
         Graph2DViewMouseWheelScrollListener wheelListener = new Graph2DViewMouseWheelScrollListener();
         wheelListener.addToCanvas(view);
    
         // The two precedent instruction is equivalent to 
         // view.getCanvasComponent().addMouseWheelListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
    {    
        // some work ...
    }  
}
```

**Problem**:
If i register my `view` object through `registerViewListeners`

```
 @Override
 protected void registerViewListeners()   
 {  
    Graph2DViewMouseWheelScrollListener wheelListener = new Graph2DViewMouseWheelScrollListener();
    wheelListener.addToCanvas(view);
 }
```

My `mouseWheelMoved` function is no longer notified:

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
{    
    // not called
}
```

Comment: How do you register the instance of  `MyClass` ? Are you saying that you are calling `view.getCanvasComponent().addMouseWheelListener(new MyClass())` and your `mouseWheelMoved` only then does not get called, when you *additionally* register the default listener?

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks. myClass has a `main` function. In this main function i create an instance of myClass, in this instance i create a JFrame, initialize all my data, .... and at the END, i register my listeners by calling `registerViewListeners()`. `wheelListener.addToCanvas(view)` take all MouseWheel_Events and `mouseWheelMoved ()` function of MyClass is no longer notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description sounds as if you have simply removed the registration for your event listener.

In the place where you instantiate `MyClass`, please also add:

```
 view.getCanvasComponent().addMouseWheelListener(myClassInstance); // register listener
```

If you don't register your listener, it will not be called, of course. Only instantiating it will not suffice.

Comment: it work, thanks. can you explain me please why this work ? now i must add this in my main function (MyClassInstance is an instance of myClass) `MyClassInstance.view.getCanvasComponent().addMouseWheelListener(MyClassInstance);`

Comment: I don't understand what kind of explanation you are looking for: If you don't register your listener, how should it ever be called? This is unrelated to yFiles. If you don't add a button click listener to a button, it won't be called, either.

Comment: yes i understend, thanks, but why when i dont call `wheelListener.addToCanvas(view);`  the function `mouseWheelMoved` of myClass is well notified ?

Comment: I simply don't believe that this would work, either. Rather I guess you had the commented out lines in place, which do exactly the same what I was proposing :-)